# Add custom div before main content in magento2

Tags: magento2, layout

I am trying to add my custom div with class and id before the maincontent.

```
 <main id="maincontent" class="page-main">
```

can i add the custom div before this line? How this can be done. Please anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try the below code:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="your.custom.name" as="your-custom" label="Your Label Name" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="your-class" htmlId="your-id" before="main.content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.file" template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml" /><!-- This is just an example -->
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

**UPDATED ANSWER AS PER COMMENT:**

Create **default.xml** under:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="your.custom.name" as="your-custom" label="Your Label Name" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="your-class" htmlId="your-id" before="page-footer"/>
</referenceContainer>
<move element="main.content" destination="your.custom.name"/>
```

Comment: we must create template file to load that div?

Comment: and the div should close after the main tag. but now it is closing before main

Comment: Do you mean to wrap the maincontent div with a extra div? like <div id="custom"><main id="maincontent" class="page-main">------</div></div> like this?

Comment: yes, i need to wrap main content within that div

Comment: i tried below code <move element="main.content" destination="your-custom" />
its not working for me

Comment: You need to use page_layout and add your own container there will be good.

Comment: can you please share that code sukumar please

Comment: header is disappeared after using that code

Comment: Can you try my updated answer?

Comment: Excellent!!. Its working great

Comment: hi @Sukumar, can you look into this issue and help me please.https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274172/quote-id-is-empty-when-inserting-multiple-records-into-cart-in-magento2

Comment: Is it possible to move one specific section to top of the page, i am using https://store-locator-m2.magento-demo.amasty.com/amlocator/summercenter/ if add description all are coming below the map, i need only one section the slider should be come to the top I mean right after breadcrumbs. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbUIo.png, i am using page builder for creating description.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
                <container name="custom_container" as="custom_container" label="Custom Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="your_class" after="main.content">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="comment.placeholder">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<!-- Lorem Ipsum -->]]></argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

In the custom container, you must put something for rendering the container `div`.

Comment: Please update me full code, its not working for me

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: I need to add the div before main.content, but your code is not like that, i need to add custom div before main content and move all the content of main into that div